# how do i click and select one by one all the items on the option dropdown using Protractor typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, webautomation

I need help in creating a typescript/javascript protractor code for this? for web automation

here is the website code:

```
<select class="form-control mainpage1" ng-options="infomation details opt1" ng-model="listVM.selectedInfo" ng-change="listVM.selectedInfoChanged()" ng-disabled="!listVM.finishLoad" style="">
<option label="dLicense Status" value="object:1002" selected="selected">License Status</option>
<option label="dLicense Category" value="object:1003">License Category</option>
<option label="ExpiryDate" value="object:1004">Expiry Date</option>
<option label="DOB" value="object:1005">Birthday</option>
<option label="License Number" value="object:1006">License Number</option>
<option label="Nationality" value="object:1007">Nationality</option>
<option label="Weight" value="object:1008">Weight</option>
<option label="Height" value="object:1009">Height</option></select>
```

i need to click one option1, then after selecting option1, select again and click option2 and so on..

i tried the following code:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.cssContainingText('[value="object:1003"]','License Status'))).click().perform()
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.cssContainingText('[value="object:1004"]','License Category'))).click().perform()
```

error occurs:

```
Failed: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("[value="object:1003"]", "License Status")
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated using css and tagName instead of xpath.

I have not tested this but you should be able to select each option by creating an array of all the option elements in that dropdown and then running a foreach on it.

```
element(by.css('.form-control mainpage1'))
  .all(by.tagName('option'))
  .forEach((option) => {
    option.click();
  });
```

Comment: xpath won't work, i need to test it on multiple browser, chrome, edge, opera, etc. So xpath is not advisable, could you provide besides xpath solution

Comment: I updated my answer based on your xpath requirement. Let me know if you still have issues

Answer (score 0):

Have toy tried this?:

First click the dropdown, so the options are displayed:

```
var dropdown = element(by.model('listVM.selectedInfo');

dropdown.click();
element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'License Status')).click();
element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'License Category')).click();
```

Of course you will have to click the dropdown everytime so the list is displayed.

Hope it helps.
Cheers.